Show that $P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left\{X_n>\sqrt{n}\right\} )=1$, given $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\infty$.
Suppose $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\infty$. I want to prove that:
$$P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left\{X_n>\sqrt{n}\right\}) =1.$$

Idea:
Since the $X_n$ are independent, the events $\left\{X_n>\sqrt{n}\right\}$ are as well independent. If I can show that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left\{X_n>\sqrt{n}\right\})=\infty,$$
then the second Borel-Cantelli lemma yields the desired result.

Question:
How can I show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left\{X_n>\sqrt{n}\right\})=\infty$? All my attempts estimating $\left\{X_n>\sqrt{n}\right\}$ from below failed.
Any hint is appreciated - thanks in advance :)

I agree. But $\sum P(X^2>n) =\sum P(|X|>\sqrt{n})$. I don’t see how to find an upper bound for this sum.

Well indeed, for that reason the statement is not true in general. You can deduce that $|X_n|>\sqrt{n}$ infinitely often, with probability $1$. But you could have, say, $X_i$ bounded above, with the infinite variance coming from the negative tail. Then it's obviously not the case that $X_n>\sqrt{n}$ infinitely often.

Ah I see - thank you. Do you know if there is any "famous" distribution with those properties? The easiest distribution I could think of had density $f_{X_n}(t)=-\frac{2}{(t-2)^3}\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,1)}(t)$.

Right, that would be a natural example. If $X$ is any non-negative random variable with finite mean $\mu$ and infinite variance, then $\mu-X$ gives an example. So does $B-(1-B)X$ where $B$ has Bernoulli($\mu/(1+\mu)$) distribution and is independent of $X$.

Thanks :) I used your first idea to construct my example. Your second example is also interesting.

First notice that the claim is in general incorrect:
Assume $X_1$ has density $f(t)=-\frac{2}{(t-2)^3}\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,1)}(t)$. The CDF of $X_1$ is thus $F(t)=\frac{1}{(t-2)^2}\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,1)}(t)+\mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty)}(t)$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_1]=0$, $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\infty$. Then:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left\{X_n>\sqrt{n}\right\})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1-P(\left\{X_n\leq\sqrt{n}\right\})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1-F(\sqrt{n})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1-1=0.$$
By the first Borel-Cantelli lemma $P(\limsup_{n\to\infty} \left\{X_n>\sqrt{n}\right\}) =0$.

We will proceed to prove that $P(\limsup_{n\to \infty} \left\{|X_n|>\sqrt{n}\right\})=1$.
Assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left\{|X_n|>\sqrt{n}\right\})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left\{X_n^2>n\right\})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left\{X_1^2>n\right\})<\infty$. By Fubini's theorem and since $t\mapsto P(X_1^2>t)$ is decreasing, we obtain:
$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]&=\int_\Omega X^2_1(\omega)\,dP(\omega)=\int_\Omega \int_0^\infty \mathbf{1}_{[0,X^2_1(\omega))}(t)\,dt\,dP(\omega)=\int_0^\infty\int_\Omega \mathbf{1}_{[0,X^2_1(\omega))}(t)\,dP(\omega)\,dt\\
&=\int_0^\infty\int_\Omega \mathbf{1}_{(t,\infty)}(X^2_1(\omega))\,dP(\omega)\,dt = \int_0^\infty P(X_1^2>t)\,dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} P(X_1^2>t)\,dt\\
&\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty  P(X_1^2>n) =  P(X_1^2>0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty  P(X_1^2>n)\leq 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty  P(X_1^2>n)<\infty. 
\end{align*}$$
This contradicts $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]=\infty$ and we conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(\left\{|X_n|>\sqrt{n}\right\})=\infty$.
